# SQL Server : CTE (recursion), set condition outside the CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, recursion, common-table-expression

Using the query below (I'm new to CTE, so this might be messy), I want to build a reverse category path of all the final categories in my database.

At the moment I have a single ID defined within the CTE itself (268707). Is there a way during my final main query that when I reference the CTE I can provide a variable?

I've put a comment in the query where I assume would be the ideal place to do this, but for the life of me can't figure out how.

```
WITH recursion(stocknode_id, short_desc, parentnode_id, level) AS
(
SELECT
    stocknode_id,
    short_desc,
    parentnode_id,
    0 AS level

FROM stock_website_node AS swn

WHERE swn.stocknode_id = 268707

UNION ALL

SELECT
    swn.stocknode_id,
    swn.short_desc,
    swn.parentnode_id,
    h.level + 1

FROM stock_website_node AS swn

INNER JOIN recursion AS h ON h.parentnode_id = swn.stocknode_id
)

SELECT
TOP 1 STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ' / ' + swn_stuff.short_desc
        FROM stock_website_node AS swn_stuff
        WHERE swn_stuff.stocknode_id IN (SELECT stocknode_id FROM recursion) /* <--- I want to pass the variable from here, I think... */
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.','varchar(max)'),
    1, 2, ''
 ) AS category_tree

FROM stock_website_node AS swn_a
```

What I'd ideally like is something that would produce results if I was to do something similar too (but doesn't appear to work):

```
WITH recursion(stocknode_id, short_desc, parentnode_id, level) AS
(
    SELECT
        stocknode_id,
        short_desc,
        parentnode_id,
        0 AS level

    FROM stock_website_node AS swn

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        swn.stocknode_id,
        swn.short_desc,
        swn.parentnode_id,
        h.level + 1

    FROM stock_website_node AS swn

    INNER JOIN recursion AS h ON h.parentnode_id = swn.stocknode_id
)

SELECT
    TOP 1 STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ' / ' + swn_stuff.short_desc
            FROM stock_website_node AS swn_stuff
            WHERE swn_stuff.stocknode_id IN (SELECT x.stocknode_id FROM recursion AS x WHERE x.xtocknode_id = swn_a.stocknode_id)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.','varchar(max)'),
        1, 2, ''
     ) AS category_tree

FROM stock_website_node AS swn_a

WHERE swn_a = 268707 OR swn_a = 268708 OR swn_a = 268709
```

I've created a codepad with the SQL to create a table variable so you can see exactly what I'm doing if you'd like to run the code (http://codepad.org/4AaZEnlq).

The table holds categories, and parentnode_id refers to the stocknode_id of the parent category. A parentnode_id of 0 means this is a top level category. The variable provided currently in the CTE is a bottom level category, and the query overall builds a category path as the result, such as:

Top Level / Second Level / Third Level / Fourth Level

During the main query I want to provide several bottom level categories and return the category path for each one, but with the current limitation of only being able to manually define a single bottom level ID rather than dynamically provide several, I'm a little stuck.

Comment: sure, you have the same options as with any other query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the constant value in the CTE with a variable and assign a value to the variable before you execute the query.

You can not pass a value to the CTE from where you have commented in the code. The value has to be assigned to the variable before the entire query.

```
declare @v int;
set @v = 268707;

with ....
(
  select ...
  where swn.stocknode_id = @v
  union all
  select ...
)
select ...
```

If you want to specify more than one stocknode_id you can add a table variable to hold the values you need and use that in a query like this:

```
declare @T table(stocknode_id int);
insert into @T values(8), (12);

with R as 
(
  select C.stocknode_id, 
         cast(C.short_desc as varchar(max)) as short_desc,
         C.parentnode_id
  from @categories as C
  where C.stocknode_id in (select T.stocknode_id from @T as T)
  union all
  select C.stocknode_id,
         C.short_desc + ' / ' +  R.short_desc,
         C.parentnode_id
  from @categories as C
    inner join R  
      on C.stocknode_id = R.parentnode_id
)
select R.short_desc
from R
where R.parentnode_id = 0;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8bd72/2)

Comment: I tried using a variable when selecting from `swn_a` however I was getting the error: `A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.`

Comment: You should assign the value to the variable **before** you execute your query.

Comment: Ah, my problem here is that I want the variable to be dynamically set, i.e. `@var = swn_a.stocknode_id`

Comment: @Ben, in your second query I guess you could just move the entire where clause to the anchor part of the recursive CTE. If not then I really don't understand your table structures and what your query does. If you want help to rewrite the query to something that works and does what you want you need to add the table structures, sample data and expected output to the question.

Comment: I've updated my question, and you can find a better example with table structure here: http://codepad.org/4AaZEnlq - thanks for the help

Comment: @Ben I have updated the answer with a query that I think does what you want.

Comment: There's some genius there, you even have a better way of joining the categories, cheers buddy!